# use select under case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to use a query which allows me to get two differents results
on depending on the filtre.
I have tried this one but it does not work.

```
CASE WHEN filtre = 10
THEN
(
 select sum(s.MONTANT_CREANCE_EMP) as creances_emp  , s.ANNEE as annee from sc01_emp s
)
ELSE
(
select sum(s.NOMBRE_CREANCE) as creances_emp  , s.ANNEE as annee from sc01_emp s

)  
END
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Is this the complete query? you are missing a select and a from clause

Comment: my objectif is :
step 1 : choose a value from the filtre
step 2 : if the filter's value equals to 10 then i want to get sum(montant)
step 3 : else if the value is not 10 , then I want to get sum(nombre)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN filtre = 10
THEN
(
 select sum(s.MONTANT_CREANCE_EMP) as creances_emp  , s.ANNEE as annee from sc01_emp s
)
ELSE
(
select sum(s.NOMBRE_CREANCE) as creances_emp  , s.ANNEE as annee from sc01_emp s
)  
END
from <table>
```

Comment: i tried it, but i got an error : filtre identificateur non valide ( ID not valid)

Comment: i tried it, but i got an error : filtre identificateur non valide ( ID not valid)

Comment: replace the "from dual" with "from <table which has filtre in it>"

Comment: another message : trop de valeur query statment ( too valuable query statment)

Comment: whats the error number, i think we may be losing something in translation

Comment: you can only have one column in the sub selects, maybe add the ",s.annee as annee" to after the CASE END statement

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not comply with the correct syntax of [case expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

```
select 
CASE 
(select count(*) from dual) WHEN 1 -- this is for test, change it to <filtre> WHEN 10
THEN
(SELECT SUM (MONTANT_CREANCE_EMP) from sc01_emp s) -- if true the result of this subquery will be affected to creances_emp
ELSE
(select SUM (NOMBRE_CREANCE) from sc01_emp s) -- if false the result of this subquery will be affected to creances_emp
END 
as creances_emp,
ANNEE as annee
from sc01_emp s;
```